# Debugging Sass in Chrome on OSX

Tags: css, macos, google-chrome, sass, google-chrome-devtools

I'm on OSX, and I'd like to be able to debug Sass-generated CSS in Chrome (or Canary) developer tools using the [new source maps feature](http://snugug.com/musings/debugging-sass-source-maps). I'm using Sass and Compass.

I've followed the [instructions](http://benfrain.com/add-sass-compass-debug-info-for-chrome-web-developer-tools/) to get Sass producting the source map file. For the benefit of anybody else who's struggling with this, the steps are:

- Install the pre-release version of Sass with `sudo gem install sass --pre`
- Check your Compass version - you need 12.2, not the 13 alpha. If you need to uninstall it you can do it with `sudo gem uninstall compass --version 0.13.alpha.2`.
- Add this to your config.rb file `sass_options = {:sourcemap => true}`.
- Go to the folder that contains your config.rb and run `sass --compass --sourcemap --watch scss:css` (this tells Sass to compile files in the scss folder to CSS files in the css folder).

If everything's worked properly, when you make a change in one of our scss files (say styles.scss), Sass will compile a new CSS file - at the same time it'll create a file called styles.css.map which contains the mapping info that should allow Chrome to point you to the source SCSS file when you select an element in Developer Tools.

I've successfully got my Sass producing this file. But unfortunately Chrome refuses to do anything with it. I've done what seem to be the recommended steps:

- Install Chrome Canary
- Go to chrome://flags and enable the setting "Enable Developer Tools
  experiments"
- Open Web Developer Tools (Function-12), click the cog in the bottom right of the window
  and on the General tab tick "Enable source maps" and on the
  Experiments tab tick "Support for Sass".
- Restart Canary

But when I inspect an element in Developer Tools I just get the same old reference to the crappy CSS file. I want to see where the element's styles originate in the SCSS file. Has anyone had any luck with this on Chrome OSX, or even with FireSass?

Comment: You should have left your question as it was and put your edit as an answer.  It's perfectly ok to answer your own questions :-).  Otherwise it stays in the "unanswered questions" pool.

Comment: Uh my question kind of morphed into a different question - I got Sass to create the source map files, but am still unable to see the references to the SCSS files in Developer Tools.

Comment: Have you tried the bare Sass watch mode, as described at https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=176807#c8 ?

Comment: Thanks Alexander, I've just tried running sass --compass --sourcemap --watch --trace scss:css. This generates the source map OK, but Chrome still shows me only the reference to the CSS.

Comment: Could you test your case on Chrome 26 (beta currently) and, if it still fails, file a bug at http://crbug.com and attach your scss code (or a sufficient subset thereof) to the bug?

Comment: O joy! It works! Thanks a lot Alexander, you've made my day. Possibly the reason I didn't see that source maps was working was that the source map only applied to one of my SCSS sheets, and I was inspecting styles defined in a CSS file that hadn't been compiled with --sourcemap.

Comment: Whew! Glad it works! Happy hacking!

Comment: its not working on windows. even i have followed all steps

Comment: Which part doesn't work Meghraj - the generation of the sourcemaps, or getting them to appear in Chrome Developer Tools? Do you see files with names like style.css.map in your CSS folder?

Comment: Approve, doesn't work getting .scss in Chrome develompent tools at Windows 7. My .css file is full of "@media -sass-debug-info" strings, and all needed setinngs ON, but chrome still show me .css styles :((

Comment: Hm.. it's tricky, there are quite a few things you have to get right - I was having trouble at first, then it came right. If you have the css.map files in your CSS folder I would look at trying this with Chrome Canary build and setting the two settings in the Chrome options mentioned above.

Comment: got this... tip: don't use sass sourcemap together with LiveReload-sublimetext2 plugin in the same time :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Source maps do actually work in OSX Chrome! I have several stylesheets in my dev environment, and I was stupidly inspecting styles that belonged to a stylesheet that didn't have a .css.map file yet. If you follow the steps above this should work for you, probably even with a current version of Chrome.

Answer (score 8):

To those having problems with the current pre-release version of SASS and compass: you are not alone and there is a workaround!

The current pre-release version is *not compatible* with compass. You need to be able to run the command 'compass' without an error, and whilst you have alpha version 162 installed, you get the LoadError.

Instead, install version 141 with the following command:

```
gem install sass -v 3.3.0.alpha.141 --pre
```

Note: you need the current stable version of compass, not the pre-release. The pre-release version of compass doesn't seem to work with build 162 *or* 141. Also, you should install compass before the pre-release version of sass, since compass will also install the currently released version of sass.

Hope that helps!